# Android Volley Post String and Get JSONArray

Tags: php, android, android-volley

How I can post a string to a PHP web server and get JSONArray in response using Volley library in Android.
 Following is my code in which I want response.
How I can post a string and get JSONArray in response using this function

See this code if it works

```
JsonArrayRequest(Method.POST,Config.VIEW_PROFILE_URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //calling method to parse json array
                        parseData(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                }){

            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("user_name", user);
                return params;
            }
        };
          MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
        }
```

//and receiving at server like

$username    =$_POST["user_name"];

Answer (score 1):

Use `getParams()` method in your request to send parameter to server
you can also set a string as body after url:

```
  JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, "url", "you can send a string here as body", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            // parse your json array 
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // handle errors here
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {   // send parameters here
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("key1", "value1");
            // add other parameters
            return params;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Comment: I want to post a user name of string value having key "user_name"
Tell me by using your method how I will post the string to php server and receive there in php?

Comment: @ZeshanMasood  just put your key value parameters in `getParams()` like i did and you can find a lot of example out there for getting parameters in php

Comment: Then wht to do with this  "you can send a string here as body"

Comment: that is optional, if you just need to send parameter you can delete that body string! and don't forget to upvote if my answer helped you

Comment: I have tried but it is not sending parameters to server

Comment: i'm sure this code works maybe you miss something in server side!    make sure you are getting parameters in php using `$_POST['key']`

Comment: dear its not working, it works if I request a string in response but not in the case of JSONArray

Comment: maybe you are sending a string from server and it's not a standard JsonArrray

Comment: I have checked all the problem is that the string is not being received at server
I am using correct form of key value pair

Comment: tell me how I will receive the string on php server if I post a string using string body

Comment: JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Method.POST,url,
             new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()   {

      @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONArray response) { //parse      }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());}
     }) {

    protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
     Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<();
     params.put("user_name", user);
     return params;
    }
   }

Answer (score 0):

Follow this here [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley) you can understand both parsing technique JSONArray and JSONObject .

Another thing is POST to server it's depend on your API , either using parameter and header or concat with URL with key-value by StringRequest.